# Where can I find more information about new syntax supported in Google style docstrings with the napoleon extension of sphinx-doc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

The sphinx-doc napoleon Google style docstrings example [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.3.4/ext/example_google.html#example-google) for version 1.3.4 shows that optional arguments for a function/method should be documented as follows:

```
param2 (str, optional): The second parameter. Defaults to None.
  Second line of description should be indented.
```

But the same page for version 1.4a0 [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/example_google.html#example-google) shows the following way to do the same thing:

```
param2 (Optional[str]): The second parameter. Defaults to None.
    Second line of description should be indented.
```

But I don't see any explanation of this new syntax in [the documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/napoleon.html#confval-napoleon_use_param). Where can I find more information about new syntax supported in Google style docstrings with the napoleon extension of sphinx-doc?

Answer (score 6):

#### In a tl;dr fashion:

Looking at the documentation in the beginning of [function `module_level_function` that you linked](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/example_google.html#example-google), one can see that:

```
def module_level_function(param1, param2=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """This is an example of a module level function.

    Function parameters should be documented in the ``Args`` section. The name
    of each parameter is required. The type and description of each parameter
    is optional, but should be included if not obvious.

    Parameter types -- if given -- should be specified according to
    `PEP 484`_, though `PEP 484`_ conformance isn't required or enforced.

    # ^^^^^ this! ^^^^
```

The final line contains a hint. Apparently, the notation introduced in [`PEP 484`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) assisted by the **[`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)** module is what you're seeing.

---

#### A small intro on the notation:

`PEP 484` is based on function annotations as described in [`PEP 3107`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/); essentially each function parameter can have an optional type specifier after its name. So, for a function like:

```
def foo(a, b): 
    pass
```

You could annotate their types in the following way:

```
def foo(a: int, b: str) -> None:
    pass
```

The introduction of type hinting brought with it *a need to formalize the way types will be indicated*; this is where the `typing` module comes in.

The `typing` module contains a good set of abstract types (and, generally, type theory mumbo-jumbo) for you to specify additional types other than standard built-ins like `int`, `str` et al. For example, the **[`Optional[str]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)** notation indicates that the parameter can take either a `str` type or a 'type' of `None` i.e it's optionally a string.

So in a nutshell, they're using the notation defined with the introduction of type hints for documenting the type of the parameters. This means that if you have a function that takes an argument that is a *List of integers*:

```
 def func(param1)
```

The documentation for it should look something like this:

```
param1 (List[int]): The first parameter containing a list of ints
```

Where [`List[int]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) comes from the notation in the typing module.

---

#### Some more examples:

Some examples where this specific notation is defined and furthe explained can be found in the [documentation of `mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/examples.html) (a static checker that inspired `PEP 484`). Common cases that one might need to document in their code are contained in the [table of built-in types](http://mypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builtin_types.html#built-in-types):

```
Type                Description
----                -----------

int                 integer of arbitrary size
float               floating point number
bool                boolean value
str                 unicode string
bytes               8-bit string
object              an arbitrary object (object is the common base class)
List[str]           list of str objects
Dict[str, int]      dictionary from str keys to int values
Iterable[int]       iterable object containing ints
Sequence[bool]      sequence of booleans
Any                 dynamically typed value with an arbitrary type
```

Others, like [`Any, Union` are defined here](http://mypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html) while generic notation described [here](http://mypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generics.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `Optional[X]` syntax isn't specific to sphinx-doc, as far as I understand. It's from the `typing` module for type hints: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html